# CakePHP Searchable Plugin of Neil Crookes

Tags: search, cakephp, full-text-search, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem with the routing while using the [Searchable Plugin](http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/11/21/cakephp-searchable-plugin/) of Neil Crookes. When I search for something the URL looks like this: 
http://localhost/search/All/sunshine

But now all the other links have the name of the plugin in their URL.
For example this:
$html->link(__('News', true), array('controller'=>'news', 'action'=>'index'));
creates this link url: **http://localhost/searchable/news** correct would be **http://localhost/news**

I already have this in app/config/routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/search/:type/:term/*', array(
  'plugin' => 'searchable',
  'controller' => 'search_indexes',
  'action' => 'index',
));
```

Any idea how I can get rid of "/searchable/" for my normal app links???

Comment: I shot Neil an email, I'm sure you'll get a reply at some point! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your normal links created by the Cake link helper you have to add this parameter **'plugin' => null**

Example:

```
$html->link(__('News', true), array('controller'=>'news', 'action'=>'index', 'plugin' => null));
```